# Kafka Producer producer.send very slow

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to write a simple Avro message producer for Kafka, using Scala.

The problem I am having is that the sending is very slow.

I am doing this:

```
val message: GenericRecord = getRandomMessage()
val serializedMessage: Array[Byte] = serializeMessage(message)

val queueMessage = new ProducerRecord[String, Array[Byte]](topic, message.get("id").toString, serializedMessage)
producer.send(queueMessage)
println("Sent Message: "+ message)
```

Both when deploying to my cluster, as well as when running from my IDE it is extremely slow to send the messages.

From what I read the message should be asynchronous and quicker than this.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you flushing each time you send? Let the Kafka client handle the buffering for you.

Comment: That was just a stupid test I was doing for the sake of trying it out. I edited and cut-out that piece of code.

Comment: Can you define what exactly you mean by poor performance?

Comment: The messages seem to get sent synchronously, one message every 10 seconds or more. (aka the "Sent Message: [...]" is printed once every 10 seconds or so)

Comment: Which Kafka version is this? And which version of the Kafka producer are you using?

Comment: Deployed I see we have kafka-2.0.2 jars in the kafka/libs, while in the project the dependency is set for kafka 2.11. I will try matching the version in my application and see if it makes a difference.\

Comment: Are you using `"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients"`?

Comment: org.apache.kafka in the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the message has been sent?

It seems that the `send` failed (or ran in a timeout) and then you print the message, which is not a guarantee of a successful sending of course.

To verify this, try to wait on the send and print the result:

`println(producer.send(queueMessage).get)`